# android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable cannot be cast to com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable

Tags: android, android-glide

I have loaded remote image to `ImageView` using below code

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)                   
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderImage)
                .into(holder.wallPaperImageView);
```

Now I want to get the bitmap from imageview

```
  Bitmap bitmap = ((GlideBitmapDrawable)holder.wallPaperImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

but above line of code throws below exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable cannot be cast to
>   com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 18):

Use this instead of that:

```
Bitmap bmp = ((GlideBitmapDrawable)holder.wallPaperImageView.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap();
```

or

```
Glide
    .with(this)
    .load(a.getAlbum_artwork())
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(300,300) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
            setBackgroundImage(resource);
        }
    });
```

Comment: How if I want SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() using original image height and width?

Comment: Then write (Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL,Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) instead of (300,300) @BagusAjiSantoso

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna get away from resizing use this (talisman):

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageUrl)       
                .asBitmap() //needed for obtaining bitmap            
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderImage)
                .into(holder.wallPaperImageView);
```

Then you are free to get bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)holder.wallPaperImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

It's working with Glide 3.8.0

Good luck,'.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Glide v4

```
 private BaseTarget target = new BaseTarget<BitmapDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(BitmapDrawable bitmap, Transition<? super BitmapDrawable> transition) {
            //here is your integration by ex: activityReference.get().toolbar.setNavigationIcon(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void getSize(SizeReadyCallback cb) {
            cb.onSizeReady(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeCallback(SizeReadyCallback cb) {}
    };
```

and after

```
Glide.with(activityReference.get().getApplicationContext())
                            .load(url of image)
                            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.img)
                                    .error(R.mipmap.img)
                                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                            .apply(circleCropTransform())
                            .into(target);
```

if you have warning 'Unchecked method ...' add before method @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score 0):

1 step

```
 Glide.with(c2).load(applicationcalass.list.get(s1).getImguri()).asBitmap().into(t1);
```

2 step

```
  Bitmap bitmap1=((BitmapDrawable) t1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```