# How can cast GlideBitmapDrawable to BitmapDrawable reciprocaly

Tags: java, android, android-glide

this code:

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.avatar);

Bitmap photo = ((GlideBitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,bos);
byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
```

return this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable cannot be cast to com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.GlideBitmapDrawable

Comment: did you try this post -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37701061/android-graphics-drawable-transitiondrawable-cannot-be-cast-to-com-bumptech-glid

Comment: In fact I loaded the image into ImageView with Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,x,y,bool) and now I would like to retrieve it with Glide (GlideBitmapDrawable) to store in the DB

Comment: This is partly what I want and reciprocaly

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
Bitmap photo = ((GlideBitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap();
```

To this:

```
Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable().getCurrent()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: did you try your code? if not, why are surprised of any downvotes?

Comment: i just give ans based on error that show in question

Comment: [GlideBitmapDrawable](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/360/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/bitmap/GlideBitmapDrawable.html) has nothing to do with `BitmapDrawable` so that cast cannot be done